# phar Class not found

Tags: php, phar

I am trying of install the dependency manager for php "composer", but "composer" needs the extension "phar". I've realized php6 comes with phar by default, but is disabled and not necessary in order to execute "phar" files.

When I try execute "composer.phar" (in the cmd: php composer.phar) it throws the error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in composer.phar on line 13.`

If I try to execute the Composer installer, "installer.php" (in the cmd: php installer.php) throws this error:

`Some settings on you machine make composer  unable to work properly. Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:`

The phar extension is missing.  How can I fix this?

Should I install it or recompile php without `--disable-phar` I am using appserv 2.6.4 (apache 2.2, php6, mysql 4).

Comment: It's because you're using a PHP version that is older than the source code requires (e.g. you're using PHP 5.2 when composer requires 5.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't use cutting edge theoretical software. PHP6 doesn't actually exist. Downgrading to a more realistic version of appserv would solve your problem. But if you insist on using 2.6.4, you should do the following:

- check that phar.so exists in the php extensions directory. If not, you need to install that extension.
- if it exists, check if it's listed in php.ini as `extension=phar.so`. If it's not, add that line.
- if it is, check that it's listed in the php.ini that command line PHP uses, too. Command line PHP and web PHP sometimes use different php.ini files, and while one might have phar.so activated, the other might not.

Comment: Thanks you Swader. i will insist a little more time with php6. I have understood that php6 comes with phar into core[1], so it not need the extension phar in the php.ini. But i don't know if i'm right. [1]http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.installation.php

Comment: I don't think you understand - php 6 literally doesn't exist. It isn't a real project. What you're playing there is someone's crazy interpretation of it and most of what you build with it will never be compatible with the real PHP6 once it comes out some time in 2017 or so. Phar is installed from 5.3.0 onwards, so there's no need to bother with php6

Comment: You right php6 doesn't exist, and the Appserv of implementation, not working good, apparently it was compiled with the instruction --disable-phar and don't allows execute phar files.